# Iterating multiple values to the specific key in jinja template using python?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, jinja2

```
I have a result like this:
{
          "read":["English"],
          "speak":["English", "French", "Portuguese", "German"],
          "write":[],
          "fluency":{"English":"Advanced", "German":"Beginner"}

        }
```

**my data mapper:**

```
{
  language:{
   speak:[],
   write:[],
   read:[],
  fluency:{}
  }
}
```

I want to display the result in a readable format like below:

```
English - Advanced- speak, read
French - speak
Italian - speak
German - Beginner - speak
```

**1st Attempt:**

```
{% for key, value in profile.get('language', '') %}
          {% for fluency, skills in value.items() %}
          <li>{{skills}}, {{fluency}} - {{(', ').join(key)}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

**Error:**

*valueerror:* too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I tried but didn't work, how can I achieve this?

Comment: It isn't clear from your code what the variable `profile` is.  Can you include more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to transform your dataset:

```
data = {
          "read":["English"],
          "speak":["English", "French", "Portuguese", "German"],
          "write":[],
          "fluency":[]
        }

def transform_data(data):
    lang = []
    [lang.extend(data[k]) for k in data]
    new_dict = {}
    for l in set(lang):
        new_dict[l] = []
        for k in data:
            if l in data[k]:
                new_dict[l].append(k)
    return new_dict

new_data = transform_data(data)
```

```
new_data = 
{'German': ['speak'],
 'English': ['read', 'speak'],
 'French': ['speak'],
 'Portuguese': ['speak']}
```

Then you can create a function which can print the data in a format you desire.

for example:

```
for k in new_data:
    print(f"{k} - {', '.join(new_data[k])}")
```

Output:

```
English - read, speak
French - speak
German - speak
Portuguese - speak
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict


json_data = {
    "language":{
        "read":["English"],
        "speak":["English", "French", "Portuguese", "German"],
        "write":[],
        "fluency":[]
    }
}

data = json_data.get('language', {})
res_dict = defaultdict(list)

for fluency, skills in data.items():
    for skill in skills:
        res_dict[skill].append(fluency)


for key, val in res_dict.items():
    lanuage = key
    fluency = ', '.join(val)

    print(f'{lanuage} - {fluency}')
```

**Output:**

```
English - read, speak
French - speak
Portuguese - speak
German - speak
```

Answer (score 0):

First find a list of unique languages then retrieve the keys from the original dictionaries to make desired string output.

```
d = {
          "read":["English"],
          "speak":["English", "French", "Portuguese", "German"],
          "write":[],
          "fluency":[]
}


langs = []
for v in d.values():
    for i in v:
        if i not in langs:
            langs += [i]
print(langs)


outputs = []
for l in langs:
    output = [l]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if l in v:
            output += [k]
    outputs += [output]

result = '\n'.join([f'{s[0]} - ' + ', '.join(s[1:]) for s in outputs])

print(result)
```

Output

```
English - read, speak
French - speak
Portuguese - speak
German - speak
```